# Why Koopman operator is defined on $L^\infty$ space?

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, operator-theory, operator-algebras

Let $(X, \mathcal{A}, \mu)$ be a measure space, $S:X\rightarrow X$ a nonsingular transformation, and $f\in L^\infty$. The operator $U:L^\infty \rightarrow L^\infty$ defined by

$
Uf(x) = f(S(x))
$

is called the Koopman operator with respect to $S$.

This is the definition of Koopman operator according to reference [1] and similar definitions can be found also in another textbooks/papers.

> But, why we need functions defined on $L^\infty$ and not on other spaces like $L^1$?

[1]: Andrzej Lasota, Michael C. Mackey-Probabilistic properties of deterministic systems-Cambridge University Press (1985)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One possible reason is that on $L^\infty$ you get an isometry. That's not the case on $L^1$. You can still define the operator, of course.

Say you take $L^1[0,1]$ with Lebesgue measure, and $S(x)=x^2$. Then, with $f(t)=t$, you have 
$$
\|f\|_1=\tfrac12,\ \ \ \|Uf\|_1=\int_0^1 t^2\,dt=\tfrac13.
$$
In fact, we can push the example and show that in $L^1$ the operator $U$ is not even bounded. Take $S$ as above and $f_n(t)=n\,1_{[0,1/n]}$. Then 
$$
\|f_n\|_1=1, \ \ \ \|Uf_n\|_1=n^2\int_0^11_{[0,1/n]},\,dt=n
$$

Comment: I also had $x^2$ in mind. Great answer. Conceivably you could define an $L^1$ subspace where it works, but then you're actually looking at intersections of $L^1$ spaces with different weights. I've run into this with my own research.

Comment: I guess one could have variations of this where you care about structure on $X$. Like if $X$ itself is a metric space, you may want $S$ to also be an isometry. There are many possibilities, but I have never thought or needed any of this :)

Answer (score 2):

Actually there is no need to define the Koopman operator just on $L^\infty$. I found it defined over several functional spaces.